# How to override .js file in strange structure

Tags: prestashop

I am working on prestashop 1.6. I have a .js file here:
`\modules\my_module\views\js\custom.js`

And I want to override it in theme.
I've tried for example:
`\themes\my_theme\modules\my_module\views\js\custom.js`

It didn't work. Nor did
`\overrides\modules\my_module\views\js\custom.js`

Where should this file be placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your file under:

```
\themes\[theme]\js\modules\[js_path_in_module]
\themes\my_theme\js\modules\my_module\views\js\custom.js
```

Comment: This is baffling, but it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure thing. I just hadn't time before to wait 10 minutes.